# React-three/fiber canvas's width and height is being overridden and I don't know why

Tags: css, reactjs, canvas, tailwind-css, react-three-fiber

I have a Next.js app that uses react-three/fiber here: https://github.com/ChristianOConnor/linear-vaporwave-react-three-fiber-typescript AND CHECKOUT `migrate-to-nextjs13` branch. The issue is regarding css. I have a react-three/fiber object rendered in the middle of the page. I have this css:

```
canvas {
  width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Which should make the react-three/fiber object take up it's entire container, but that is overridden and reset to 300px by 150px. See here:
[image]

As you can see, the css set to `canvas` for `width` and `height` is crossed out.

It should look like this (I manually in the web console changed the width and height to 100%)
[image]

I've made my source code available in the link towards the top of the post, just remember to switch the code to the `migrate-to-nextjs13` branch.

So why is the `canvas`'s `width` and `height` being overriden and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`<Canvas>` takes the same width/height as its nearest absolute or relative parent. you don't need to target canvas in css directly, just make sure the container where canvas resides in has position: absolute (or relative) and is scaled correctly.